# How can I use println in java everywhere in my project without the full namespace System.out.println?

Tags: java

When I am debugging, I often print to stdout. This means writing the fairly long statement `System.out.println(...);` all over the place. Plenty of languages have much shorter global print methods. How can I accomplish something similar in java? Is there a way to set up static imports globally across all java files in a project somehow with either maven or gradle?

Comment: Is it the typing you take issue with, or the length of the code?

Comment: Most IDEs have shortcut code completions, like `sout` for example

Comment: @andykais, Which IDE you are using?

Comment: If you really want to, you can create a class that has a reference to the PrintStream out and use that variable instead of System.out.

Comment: “Plenty of languages have much shorter global print methods.”  Java doesn’t have *any* global methods.  All methods must belong to an object or class.  Though you might find loggers make things a little shorter, since you can do `private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(ThisClassOfMine.class.getName());` and then write `log.info("Computing result.");` and so on.

Comment: BTW: `System.out` isn't a "namespace", it is the field `out` of the class `java.lang.System`. That said, using a lot of `System.out.println()` is usually a bad idea (especially in a highly concurrent application). You may want to consider using the system logger, or java.util.logging (which the system logger uses by default).

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own methods to achieve this

**To print something without a new line**

```
public static void p(Object printThis) {

    System.out.print(printThis);
}
```

**To print something with a new line**

```
public static void pl(Object printThisWithNewLine) {

    System.out.println(printThisWithNewLine);
}
```

And in the code, you can use the `p()` or the `pl()` methods based on your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Don’t print spam. Use the debugger instead.

Why?

1. It allows you to see the value in real time at multiple steps in the program. You can see how the value changes at various breakpoints and manually increment steps.
2. It separates the concerns of debugging from programming. You shouldn’t have a bunch of print statements lying around your code. The odds are good you’ll forget one when you ship it.
3. It allows you to change values of variables while debugging. This is extremely useful in troubleshooting.

If you can’t use the debugger for whatever reason, use instead a logging library. This allows you to silence your debugging statements by default when running production code and set the log levels to the appropriate severity, silencing ones that are too fine-grained. It also works better with logging software because it’s standardized.

Please don’t print spam. You will thank yourself later, as will the person who uses your code later.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a class that reference System.out.  You may have to complete other methods but here's the idea.

```
class O {
    static  java.io.PrintStream o = System.out;
    public static void p(String s){ o.print(s);}
    public static void p(int i){o.print(i);}
    public static void pl(String s){ o.print(s);}
    public static void pl(int i){o.print(i);}
}
```

Then use it wherever you want.

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        O.p("hello");
        O.pl("world");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be archived using static import.

First create an interface (or class) containing one or more static methods, that should be shared with other classes:

```java
package demo;  // use the appropriate package here

public interface Output {

    public static void println(String message) {
        System.out.println(message);
    }

    public static void printf(String format, Object... args) {
        System.out.printf(format, args);
    }
}
```

This methods can be used *directly* by using a static import:

```java
import static demo.Output.*;

class TestOutput {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        println("Testing Output");
    }
}
```

---

Using a class instead of an interface:

```java
package demo;  // use the appropriate package here

public final class Output {

    private Output() {
        throw new InstantiationError("should not be instantiated");
    }
    
    public static void println(String message) {
        System.out.println(message);
    }

    public static void printf(String format, Object... args) {
        System.out.printf(format, args);
    }
}
```

The *test* code is the same.

The class is declared `final`, so it cannot be extended. The constructor throws an exception, to avoid instance creation. These can be changed if needed, for example to have some additional output processing.

---

I am not sure if I would use such solution just to avoid writing `System.out.`, but, for some applications, it has the advantage of having all output going through the same class/methods.